# How to change the position of the last UItableview cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am loading different components in the tableview. Each component is having different types of data such as video, image, quick reply and other component.

I am able to load all the data and added to the table view and table view height is adjusted based on the data response.

Now my requirement would be one specific component is displayed at the bottom of the screen always. How do I change the Y position of the particular component?

The problem which I am facing now, not able to change the position of that component.

Comment: what about tableview footerview

Answer (score 0):

You can use another UIView fixed at the bottom of the screen below your tableView. You can put that component in that UIView. This way it will be fixed at the bottom.

Another option is using a TableViewController instead of a TableView. That way you can have static cells. You can set the last cell at the bottom however you like. It never changes.

Comment: I've used custom view and fixed in the bottom. As per the requirement the custom view should be scrolled along with the table view. For that reason only I am finding some solution. The second option which you suggested that it ll work only the static cells with static content. In my case I am loading the dynamic component at run time. So it won't work I think.

Comment: So, are you basically required to always display the same content in the last row of your UITableView object? Would that solve your problem? If that's the case it is easy. Just tell me and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I want to keep one custom component in the bottom always. That component is having horizontal scroll of the button content. Based on the response, I am adding the button dynamically.